# How to convert a size (m, n) to a size (m, 1, n) array?

Tags: arrays, type-conversion

I have a train_dataset with a size (237738, 25) See the picture below and it is presented using pandas data frame. You can convert it to a NumPy array using train_set = train_set.values. How can I convert this array to a
size of (237738,1,25) array?

Thanks!!!

[image]

Comment: That's a dataframe, not an array as far as I can tell. Please add appropriate language and library tags, and provide an MCVE. At least let us know the datatype of `train_set`

Answer (score 0):

just found out, actually can directly use numpy.reshape function. I.e. train_set = np.reshape(train_set, (train_set.shape[0],1,train_set.shape[1]))!